# libav streaming h264 over mpegts to rtmp server

Tags: c++, streaming, h.264, libav, mpeg2-ts

I'm working on an application where I want to stream h264 over mpegts 
to a rtmp server (FMS, C++ RTMP Server, Wowza).  I'm looking at the 
output-example.c of libav. I stripped all the audio for now to keep it
simple.

I'm using this code as a test (not working):
https://gist.github.com/fb450aee77471a1d86f3#comments

What am I doing wrong there?

Thanks